# How can I rename packed image files and then unpack all with new names?

Tags: texturing, blend-files

I recently purchased a few scenes from BlenderMarket, but the textures all have nonsensical names, or names that would easily cause conflicts (like 002.jpg). I've been manually unpacking and renaming the texures, and then replacing them in the scene. Unfortunately this process is taking forever.

Here's an example.

**Original Textures:**

[image: Original Textures]

**Renamed Textures (What I did manually):**

[image: New Textures]

What I really need is a way to automate this process, or just a less time consuming way to do it. If I can rename the textures packed into the file directly in blender, that would be awesome. Or if someone could point me to a script or addon that does this, that would also be great.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

My workflow for handling texture images is to first pack all the images into blender. Then rename the texture name and then unpack the blender file with correct texture names.

However there is a caveat here: An image in blender has a name and file name. The image name we see in image node in shader graph are referring to the name of the image. When blender unpack the file, it uses the file name for writing to disk.

We can inspect the file name in *Outliner, Data API* panel.

[image: Data View in Blender]

I made a little snippet for renaming the file name to match the image name. You can run this snippet under *Python Console* panel.

```py
for image in D.images:
    fp = f"//textures\\{image.name}"
    image.filepath = fp
    for pf in image.packed_files:
        pf.filepath = fp
```

Before running the script, make sure:

1. All image name are unique
2. Image name got their extension included
3. Make a backup

After running the script, do an unpack and the image filenames should align with the name shown in blender.

This is tested on Blender 3.0, Windows.